# Is there a chance my scoped service will get disposed before the scope ends?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, service

I'm trying to create a service that will run in the background and run a timer task at a certain interval.  I can't add it as a hosted service because it needs to only start running after another hosted service has done its startup, so I'm creating a scope within that hosted service and running this one by getting it as a scoped service:

```
    services.AddScoped<TaskTimer>();
    services.AddHostedService<BotService>();
```

This timer service is implemented as:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyBot;

internal class TaskTimer : IDisposable {
    #region Private vars

    private readonly ILogger<TaskTimer> _log;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public TaskTimer(ILogger<TaskTimer> log) {
        _log = log;

        _log.LogInformation("Starting task timer");

        // [start timer here]
    }

    #endregion

    public void Dispose() {
        _log.LogInformation("Stopping task timer");

        // [stop timer here]
    }
}
```

... then within the main bot service:

```
public class BotService : BackgroundService {
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) {
        // [do init here...]

        using (var botServiceScope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope()) {
            // Start task timer
            _ = botServiceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TaskTimer>();

            // [await stoppingToken]
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work as I'm testing it now, but I'm wondering whether there's a chance the task timer could get disposed before the scope `using` statement closes, because I'm throwing away the return value from `GetRequiredService`.  Is it guaranteed to only get disposed when the scope closes even though I'm not holding a reference to the service instance?

Comment: As long as you wait the operation before `botServiceScope.Dispose()` is called (at the end of the using block) you should be safe. That said, a more common pattern is to separate the starting logic from the constructor, by introducing a `Start()` method. This obeys the [simple injection constructors](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/) rule and makes it more obvious to the reader of your code what is going on.

Comment: If you started the timer in the `Start` method, would you still use the `Dispose` method to stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a chance my scoped service will get disposed before the scope ends?
> because I'm throwing away the return value from GetRequiredService

"Throwing away" will not lead to call of the `Dispose` method, GC does not care about class implementing `IDisposable`, it cares only about [finalizers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/finalizers) (though finalizer can share implementation or directly call `Dispose`). `IDisposable.Dispose` is only called "explicitly" (either via direct call or via `using`). In case of the DI (build-in one) - it will dispose and "dereference" the scoped dependency only after the containing scope is disposed, it will preserve the reference until that (it does not know anything about the visibility scopes and it need to maintain the single instance per scope guarantee).

> I can't add it as a hosted service because it needs to only start running after another hosted service has done its startup.

You actually can. Just provide some synchronization mechanism (similar to the example in the docs [for caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/caching#photo-service-scenario)):

```
// synchronization primitive, wrap in some meaningful class:
builder.Services.AddSingleton(new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1)); 
builder.Services.AddHostedService<MyServ2>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<MyServ1>();

public class MyServ1 : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphoreSlim;

    public MyServ1(SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim)
    {
        _semaphoreSlim = semaphoreSlim;
    }

    public override async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // init sync/async
        Console.WriteLine("Starting 1");
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Console.WriteLine("Started 1");
        _semaphoreSlim.Release();
        await base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nameof(MyServ1));
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
    }
}

public class MyServ2 : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphoreSlim;

    public MyServ2(SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim)
    {
        _semaphoreSlim = semaphoreSlim;
    }

    public override async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("starting 2");
        
        await base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nameof(MyServ2));
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
    }
}
```

Second approach (which I would not recommend though and it is provided only for completeness) is to rely on the internal workings of the hosted services - register services in correct order and perform blocking initialization of the first one:

```
builder.Services.AddHostedService<MyServ1>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<MyServ2>();

public class MyServ1 : BackgroundService
{
    public override async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // blocking init:
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Console.WriteLine("starting 1");
        }
        
        await base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nameof(MyServ1));
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
    }
}

public class MyServ2 : BackgroundService
{
    public override async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("starting 2");
        
        await base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nameof(MyServ2));
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
    }
}
```